# Matplotlib: returned AXes from functions to be inserted into new subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, matplotlib, subplot

So I have these two functions to plot timeSeries and histograms.

```
ax1 = plotTimeSeries(df=dfDelay_Vector)
ax2 = plotHistogram( df=dfDelay_Hist)
```

Each of those return an `ax` object and they both produce a plot. So far, so good.

Now, I have a new function, that tries to introduce those plots into a subplot. `axes` is a list such as `axes = [ax1,ax2]`

```
def drawSubPlots(rows, cols, axes):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols)
    for i in range(len(axes)):
        ax[i] = axes[i]
```

... but all I get is an empty figure.

[image]

How can I insert returned axes into a new subplot?

Thanks!

Comment: From the [Notes](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) in the `plt.subplot` documentation: 
"Creating a subplot will delete any pre-existing subplot that overlaps with it beyond sharing a boundary"

Comment: @Lucas, sorry but I don't quite follow your point and how does it relate to my question. On the other hand I admit I don't really understand how is it that different subplots (in my case, 3) overlap among them ... I just want to pass `ax`es over as arguments to a function, want to know if that is even possible ...

Comment: I think that when you create the subplot with the function `drawSubPlots` you delete the old plots. 
Why not create the subplots first? and you pass the axes to the function? something like: `plotTimeSeries(df=dfDelay_Vector, ax=ax1)`

Comment: oh! I see what you mean ... let me try that out ...

Comment: I would recommend reading the [coding styles](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#coding-styles) section of the usage guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after following the suggestions from people above, I came to the following:

```
fig, ax = drawSubPlots(2,1)
ax1     = plotTimeSeries(df=dfDelay_Vector, ax=ax[0] )
ax2     = plotHistogram( df=dfDelay_Hist,   ax=ax[1] )
```

Doing so, produces the next subplot:

[image]

Still need to tune the plots themselves (orientation of xtickslabels, fontsize, keep color of series among subplots, size of bars in the histogram) but the main thing is covered!

Thanks!